# HTML form submission in Android app

Tags: java, android, form-submit, forms

My requirement is to store a submitted HTML form in Android application/device. I have an android app in which I'll run an HTML page with form.When the form is submitted on HTML page, I want the input fields from form to be transferred to some Java class inside app where I would store them in their respective data structures.

I have this requirement because I need to make app work offline.

What my little understanding is that I need some java class to be put in the 'action' method of 'form'.

Please guide me how can I make it happen!

Please ask me if I'm not clear enough about my question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using a `Webview`. If you are, you can enable Javascript and then use `localStorage`. This way you will keep everything in HTML / Javascript.

You can then re-populate the form by checking (with Javascript) if there is a `localStorage` item for the form element on load.

Alternatively, you can enable the [Android Javascript Interface annotation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) which will allow you to call Java from Javascript in a Webview.